# не могу найти ошибку вызывающую segmentation fault ( язык С )

Tags: c, память, malloc, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* likes(size_t n, const char *const names[n])
{
   char *result;
   size_t m;
   size_t nn;
   size_t count;

if (!(n))
   return("no one likes this");
if (n == 1)
   {
   m = strlen((char *)names[0]);
   if (!(result = (char *)malloc(m + 1 + 5 + 4 + 2)))
      return(NULL);
   sprintf(result, "%s likes this", (char *)names[0]);
   return(result);
   }
if (n == 2)
   {
   m = strlen((char *)names[0]) +  strlen((char *)names[1]);
   if (!(result = (char *)malloc(m + 1 + 5 + 2 + 8 + 3)))
      return(NULL);
   sprintf(result, "%s and %s like this", (char *)names[0], (char *)names[1]);
   return(result);
   }
if (n == 3)
   {
   m = strlen(names[0]) + strlen(names[1]) + strlen(names[2]);
   if (!(result = (char *)malloc(m + 1 + 2 + 5 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 3)))
      return(NULL);
   sprintf(result, "%s, %s and %s like this", (char *)names[0], (char *)names[1], (char *)names[2]);
   return(result);
   }
if (n >= 4)
   {
   m = strlen((char *)names[0]) + strlen((char *)names[1]);
   nn = n;
   count = 0;
   while(nn)
   {
      nn/=10;
      count++;
   }
   if (!(result = (char *)malloc(m + 2 + 5 + count + 1 + 6 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 3)))
      return(NULL);
   sprintf(result, "%s, %s and %d others like this", (char *)names[0], (char *)names[1], (int)(n - 2));
   return(result);
   }
return(NULL);
}
```

это мой ответ на задание "who like this" в codewars . при сдаче ответа она выдает Signal code: 11 сегфолт. два дня не могу понять что я не так делаю с паматью. ПАМАГИТЕ!!

Пример задания:

```
* return must be an allocated string
* do not mutate input

likes({})
    // should return "no one likes this"

likes({"Peter"})
    // should return "Peter likes this"

likes({"Jacob", "Alex"})
    // should return "Jacob and Alex like this"

likes({"Max","John","Mark"})
    // should return "Max, John and Mark like this"

likes({"Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"})
    // should return "Alex, Jacob and 2 others like this"
```

Пример теста:

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
#include <stddef.h>

char* likes(size_t n, const char *const names[n]);

Test(Sample_Tests, should_pass_all_the_tests_provided) {
  {
     const char *const names[0] = {};
     char* expected = "no one likes this";
     char* submitted = likes(0, names);
     cr_assert_str_eq(expected, submitted,"Expected : %s\nSubmitted: %s\n\n", expected, submitted);
     free(submitted); submitted = NULL;
  }
  {
     const char *const names[1] = {"Peter"};
     char* expected = "Peter likes this";
     char* submitted = likes(1, names);
     cr_assert_str_eq(expected, submitted,"Expected : %s\nSubmitted: %s\n\n", expected, submitted);
     free(submitted); submitted = NULL;
  }
  {
     const char *const names[2] = {"Jacob", "Alex"};
     char* expected = "Jacob and Alex like this";
     char* submitted = likes(2, names);
     cr_assert_str_eq(expected, submitted,"Expected : %s\nSubmitted: %s\n\n", expected, submitted);
     free(submitted); submitted = NULL;
  }
  {
     const char *const names[3] = {"Max", "John", "Mark"};
     char* expected = "Max, John and Mark like this";
     char* submitted = likes(3, names);
     cr_assert_str_eq(expected, submitted,"Expected : %s\nSubmitted: %s\n\n", expected, submitted);
     free(submitted); submitted = NULL;
  }
  {
     const char *const names[4] = {"Alex", "Jacob", "Mark", "Max"};
     char* expected = "Alex, Jacob and 2 others like this";
     char* submitted = likes(4, names);
     cr_assert_str_eq(expected, submitted,"Expected : %s\nSubmitted: %s\n\n", expected, submitted);
     free(submitted); submitted = NULL;
  }
 }
```

Comment: морально готов к любой критике

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала - вы пишете, в частности,

```
return("no one likes this");
```

а потом

```
 char* submitted = likes(0, names);
 ...
 free(submitted);
```

Ну и как делать `free` для просто строки, а не результата `malloc`? Должна функция возвращать динамически выделенную память - пусть это делает всегда, на всех путях...

И еще - вот эти мучения с

```
+ 1 + 6 + 2 + 4 + 4 + 3
```

Зачем? Если функции `sprintf` передать `NULL` в качестве первого аргумента, она сама вернет размер памяти, который ей требуется. Вот, почитайте [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). Пример оттуда же:

```
const char *fmt = "sqrt(2) = %f";
int sz = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, sqrt(2));
char buf[sz + 1]; // note +1 for terminating null byte
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, fmt, sqrt(2));
```

Ну, в вашем случае нужно третью строку заменить на

```
char * buf = malloc(sz + 1);
```

Кстати, в C приведение типа возврата `malloc` излишне, это в C++ обязательно.

Comment: я проглядел в тесте  free в первом случае. мой тест отличался от теста на codewars, поэтому я так и не нашел ответа на этот вопрос (надо было работать с их тестом).  По правде сначала я писал все через самописную strcat , Но потом начал параноить из за этой ошибки  и начал сомневаться в самописном решении на strcat , что подтолкнуло меня использовать printf которую я еще не реализовал и только дебажил ей. Это к слову о вашей достаточно элегантной записи через snprintf. В последнем я привожу тип как раз из за этой особенности, чтобы было легче перейти в дальнейшем на C++. Огромное вам спасибо.

Comment: А можно сразу и `asprintf()`.